# How to do indefinite person with verbs

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, conjugation

In English you can conjugate like so:

> I eat
>   You eat
>   He/she/it eats
>   We eat
>   You all eat
>   They eat

But you can also conjugate with a variety of “indefinite” pronouns:

> One eats
>   Everyone eats
>   No one eats
>   Few eat
>   Some eat
>   Many eat
>   Etc.

I’m wondering what this would look like in Latin and how you would categorise it in terms of person and number? E.g., is “one eats” first, second or third person? Is it singular or plural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules in Latin are somewhat the same as in English: use a separate word for the subject, then conjugate the verb to agree with it.

In English, you say "one *eats*" but "many *eat*" because the former is third person singular and the latter is third person plural; in Latin, the same applies: *aliquis edit*, *multī edunt*.

Direct translations of the words you ask for are *aliquis* "someone", *omnis* "every person", *nemō* "no one", *paucī* "a few", *aliquī* "some people", and *multī* "many". But you can really use any adjective or noun like this: *ūnus* "exactly one person", *duō* "two people", *malī* "the evil people", and so on.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Draconis's suggestions, you can use the passive voice to express an indefinite 'agent':

> Romam itur. "[indefinite subject / 'it'] is being gone to Rome" => "One goes to Rome", in context probably "We/I/they/etc. go to Rome".
>
> In horto esum est. "One ate in the garden".
>
> Noctis pugnandum est. "One ought to fight at night".

Comment: I think this is a more apposite answer than Draconis'

Comment: In agreement. cf. Fischer, Vol. 2, p. [72](https://books.google.com/books?id=9SXgAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false), § 460, 2., 3.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, *on specific conditions*, one can also express an indefinite person **using the present subjunctive(*) of the 2nd person singular.** In a manner not not unsimilar to "[Generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you)" in English and other languages.

According to [A&G (§518)](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/general-conditions) in *general conditions* :

> The subjunctive is often used in the 2nd person singular, to denote the act of an indefinite subject (you = any one). Here the present indicative of a general truth may stand in the apodosis.

> Virtūtem necessāriō glōria, etiamsī **tū** id nōn **agās**, cōnsequitur. (Tusc. 1.91)
> Glory necessarily follows virtue, even if that is not **one's** aim.

For a detailed reading, one can [consult](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdf/10.1086/358905): Hale, William Gardner. "An Unrecognized Construction of the Latin Subjunctive: The Second Person Singular in General Statements of Fact." (1906).

---

(*) Several sources (like of William Gardner) claim that the **indicative** can be also used in general statements. e.g:

> Bis **peccas** cum peccanti obsequium commodas. ( Publil. 52.). You sin doubly when you humour a sinner